# ClickOnce cancellation of Application Rollback

Tags: clickonce, rollback

ClickOnce Roll-Back

Once a single user rolls back one version, how can the application check for this locally and give the option to install the latest version?

Our Clickonce applications are numerous due to the continuous integration aspect of the technology. We have a new version and all the user has to do is accept the installation. A new version can even be globally rolled back by simply moving the version specific .application file up to the main root path from the "Application Files" subdirectory. If a specific user needs to roll-back, he can simply run the uninstall string from the registry or use the control panel to revert to the previous version.

One issue I haven't been able to resolve is getting that user back into the "Upgrade check" loop. I've been using the [Sysinternals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winternals) tool, [Process Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor), to follow the registry and file system logic of ClickOnce. Reviewing the tools data it tells me the location of the local ClickOnce files and the registry entries for the SideBySide settings. However, I can't figure out what setting to change in order to override a local user who has done an individual roll-back. I'm sure their must be a change to the SideBySide PackageMetadata in the registry to accomplish this task.

Specifically, I'd like to have two selections available to the user for any version of the ClickOnce application running. One selection to force a rollback and another selection to allow the user to get back on track with the current updates. I can only accomplish the first in code.

```
\\Server\Share\{clickonce}.application
\\Server\Share\Application_Files\{clickonce}_{version x}\{Clickonce}.application
\\Server\Share\Application_Files\{clickonce}_{version y}\{Clickonce}.application

Process:
dfsvc.exe

Local Storage:
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\{unique}\{unique}
C:\Users\plugged\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\{unique}\{unique}.application

Registry:
HKCU\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Deployment\SideBySide\2.0\PackageMetadata
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{guid}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the solution.  To get the ClickOnce application back into the upgrade loop, simply link to the current server version from the local version.  Your ClickOnce application uses the desktop icon to launch.  Even if the user rolled back the local version the desktop icon doesn't change, it still points to the server location.  Yet, it will only run the local rolled back version and won't check for updates.  The solution is to have method which starts a process which links to the server's current .application file.  This can be done by creating a new process variable, then setting the "StartInfo" with the WorkingDirectory and Filename of the ClickOnce application.

\Server\Share{ClickOnce}.application

dgp